# How to extend angled lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In words what I'm trying to do is:
"Extend the three green lines from their specified point of origin at their specified angle to meet the blue line"
How would you recommend doing this?

```
\def \tubeLength{10}
\def \lightLength{5}
\def \angleDown{340}
\def \lightSpacing{1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]

% tube
\draw (0,0) -- (\angleDown:\tubeLength);
\draw (0,0) ++(\angleDown-270:4*\lightSpacing) -- ++(\angleDown:\tubeLength);

% diffracted light
\foreach \y in {\lightSpacing, 2*\lightSpacing, 3*\lightSpacing}
  \draw[green] (0,\y) -- ++(\angleDown:\lightLength);

% lense center line
\path (0,0) -- (\angleDown:\lightLength) coordinate (A)
  node[below left] {A};
\path [draw, very thick, blue] (A) -- ++(\angleDown-270:4*\lightSpacing)
  coordinate (B)
  node[above right,black] {B};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you used the `tikz` library `calc` then you can write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\def \tubeLength{10}
\def \lightLength{5}
\def \angleDown{340}
\def \lightSpacing{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  % tube
  \draw (0,0) -- (\angleDown:\tubeLength);
  \draw (0,0) ++(\angleDown-270:4*\lightSpacing) -- ++(\angleDown:\tubeLength);

  % lense center line
  \path (0,0) -- (\angleDown:\lightLength) coordinate (A) node[below left] {A};
  \path [draw, very thick, blue] (A) -- ++(\angleDown-270:4*\lightSpacing) coordinate (B) node[above right,black] {B};

  % diffracted light
  \foreach \y/\x in {\lightSpacing/1, 2*\lightSpacing/2, 3*\lightSpacing/3}
    {
      \coordinate (DL\x) at (0,\y);
      \draw[green] (DL\x)  -- ($(A)!(DL\x)!(B)$);
    }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax `($<coordinate>!<projection coordinate>!<angle>:<second coordinate>$)` will give you the projection of the given point to the desired line.

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for and also led me to an interesting section of the manual.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply rotate your coordinate systems about `\angleDown` you don’t need to change anything with your code except to remove `\angleDown`.

Though, I removed as much `\def`s as simply possible.
You can adjust both `tubeLength` and `lightLength` by changing the `y` vector of PGF/TikZ, the default is `y=1cm`. Setting it to `y=2cm`, will make the `tubeLength` 20cm long and the `lightLength` 10cm (at least without `scale`).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, rotate=340, every label/.append style={black}]
\def\lightLength{5}
% tube
\draw    (0,0) -- ++ (right:10) coordinate (tubeLength);
\draw (-270:4) -- ++ (tubeLength);
% diffracted light
\foreach \y in {1,...,3} \draw[green] (0,\y) -- ++(right:\lightLength);
% lense center line
\path (right:\lightLength)                     coordinate[label=below left:A]  (A);
\path [draw, very thick, blue] (A) -- ++(up:4) coordinate[label=above right:B] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with PSTricks. Unfortunately, there is no `($ (A)!0.25!(B) $)`-like syntax in PSTricks so the `temp` as an auxiliary node is necessary.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](8,8)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={-90,90},CurveType=polyline,linecolor=blue](3,1){A}(5,6){B}
    \psline([offset=2]{A}B)([offset=-2]{A}B)
    \psline([offset=2]{B}A)([offset=-2]{B}A)
    \multido{\n=.25+.25}{3}{%
        \nodexn{\n(B)-\n(A)+(A)}{temp}
        \psline[linecolor=green]([offset=3]{B}temp)(temp)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]